# algorithm2e single-line control structures

Tags: algorithm2e

I am using `algorithm2e` for formatting pseudo-code: is it possible to compress single-instructions control structure to one single line?

For example I would like to modify this so that `l.sort()` appears on the same line as `foreach`:

```
\begin{algorithm}[htb]
  \ForEach{$l \in list\_of\_lists$}{  $l.sort()$\;  }
  \caption{...}
  \label{...}
\end{algorithm}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the command `\lForEach`. See https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.pdf page 33.

```
\begin{algorithm}[htb]
  \lForEach{$l \in list\_of\_lists$}{  $l.sort()$\;  }
  \caption{...}
  \label{...}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot! I didn't see that, it is in the examples but even google coldn't find it by searching "one line for" or "single line control structure"

Comment: I also removed the `\;` in order to prevent a blank line to be added.

Comment: You're welcome! I know how it is, sometimes google is not very helpfull with latex issues, even easy ones in retrospective. Started to use this site some days ago and it's so helpfull and I learned a lot.